# How to increment an iterator while iterating ("skipping some entries")?

Tags: python, iterator

I iterate over a list and on some conditions I would like to skip a few elements. A typical example are lines in a file that I output, then do not output the ones between specific lines, and finally output the rest.

An example of what I would like to achieve (the code does not work as expected) :

```py
mylist = list(range(10))
for entry in mylist:
    if entry == 5:
        while entry < 8:
            next(mylist)    # ← this is the line I want to address
    else:
        print(entry)
```

What I was expecting on the output are `0` to `5`, then nothing between `5` and `8`, and finally `9`.

The exception I get is `TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator` (I thought it was).

Is there a straightforward way to skkip iterator entries?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Thank you. I understand how `next(mylist)` will skip entry `5` but I do not see how to run this `next` in a loop that would skip several lines (until a condition is met - in my case `entry => 8`.

Answer (score 2):

`mylist` is an *iterable*, not an iterator, so you can't call `next` directly on it. But you can create an iterator from it!

```py
mylist = list(range(10))
mylist_iter = iter(mylist)
for entry in mylist_iter:
    if entry == 5:
        while next(mylist_iter) < 8:
            pass
    else:
        print(entry)
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
9
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your own solution work as expected with only two changes

```
mylist = iter(range(10))
for entry in mylist:
    if entry == 5:
        while entry < 8:
            entry = next(mylist)
    else:
        print(entry)
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an iterator in the for loop if you want to move it forward arbitrarily.  You have to be careful not to skip values or exceed the data however.

```
mylist = list(range(10))
mylistIter = iter(mylist)
for entry in mylistIter:
    if entry == 6: # to include 5, you must skip after processing it.
        try: 
             while entry < 8: 
                 entry = next(mylistIter) 
        except StopIteration: break
    # do not use else: here or you'll skip item '8'
    print(entry)              

0
1
2
3
4
5
8
9
```

alternatively, you could use the `continue` statement:

```
mylist = list(range(10))
for entry in mylist:
    if 5 < entry < 8: continue
    print(entry)
```